# CWE-611: Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference with XSL include

Tags: .net, xml, cwe, xsl

Veracode reports that the below code is susceptible to [CWE-611: Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/611.html).

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(xslwithospath);
StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
```

Unfortunately I can't set the XMLResolver to null because the XSLT uses an include

```
<xsl:include href="localfileNameWithoutPath"/>
```

Is the only resolution to rewrite the XSLT so that it does not have XSL includes, and then set the resolver to null?

[Can I use an Xml Secure Resolver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca3076-insecure-xslt-script-execution?view=vs-2019), and if so how?